# Tooltips overlap in vueform slider

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, vue-formulate, vue-slider-component

I'm using this slider (https://github.com/vueform/slider#multiple-slider) in one of my form field and for some reasons, both the tooltips are stuck at one place.

Template Code of the slider component:

```
<template>
  <div class="input-container">
    <label class="input-label">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="input-field">
      <Slider 
        v-model="value"
        :min="0"
        :max="4500"
        :showTooltip="always"
        :format="formatTooltip"
        class="slider-red"
        />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script>

import Slider from '@vueform/slider'
import '@vueform/slider/themes/default.css';

export default {
  name: 'RangeSlider',
  components: {
    Slider,
  },
  props: {
    label: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: [0, 4500],
    }
  },
  watch: {
    activeButton(newValue) {
      this.activeButtonValue = newValue
    },
  },
  methods: {
    formatTooltip(val) {
      return `$${val}`
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.input-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: #d7c8f1;
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration-color: white;
}

.input-field {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid var(--secondary-color);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.space-right {
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid var(--secondary-color);
  padding: 4px !important;
  border-radius: 12px !important;
  color: #101828 !important;
  background-color: #f9fafb;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-weight: 500;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.content-button {
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid var(--secondary-color);
}

.slider-red {
  --slider-connect-bg: #EF4444;
  --slider-tooltip-bg: #EF4444;
  --slider-handle-ring-color: #EF444430;
}

</style>
```

I have tried formatting the width/height of the class, but it doesn't seem to work.

The problem state:

[image]

Comment: Your *tooltip* value is set to ```value: [0, 4500]```

Comment: Hi, I switched it to a smaller number like 10 and it's still overlapping both the points right in middle.

Comment: Changing ```:showTooltip="always"``` to ```thumb-label="always"``` or just ```thumb-label``` may help you in some way.

Comment: I added the changes but it still appears overlap. Removing :showTooltip="always" and adding thumb-label="always" just removed the tooltip labels.

Comment: I put an answer. But i'm not sure if it could work, but if possible to you to make a playground, can you provide it? so debugging should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You are just giving the value in an array. I'm not sure if it's totally work, so until you give a working playground, I hope I could help in some way.

*Replace these*

```
data() {
    return {
      value: [0, 4500],
    }
  }
```

*To*

```
data: () => ({
  tooltip: {
    value:[0 ,4500],
    format: function (value) {
      return `$${Math.round(value)}`
    }
  },
})
```

And your *template* view will look like this.

```
<div class="input-container">
  <label class="input-label">{{ tooltip.value }}</label>
  <div class="input-field">
    <Slider
      :showTooltip="always"
      :format="formatTooltip"
      class="slider-red"
      v-model="tooltip.value"
      v-bind="tooltip"
    ></Slider>
  </div>
</div>
```